# Bash script to search multiple strings in text file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have created a script to search a string in a text file and outputs all the lines with that string:

```
    #!/bin/sh
STRING=$1
FILE=dsat.txt
if grep -q $STRING $FILE;
  then
        echo -e "$(grep $STRING $FILE)\n"
else
        echo "Not found"
        exit 0
fi
```

I want to expand on this where i have multiple details in the text file such as

```
Word1 Word2 - Word3 Word4 Word5
Word1 Word6 Word3 Word7 Word8
```

And in the search i search for "Word1 Word3"

I want it to still output these lines as the search case matches this line.

Is this possible using a grep?

Update:

```
    #!/bin/sh
FILE=text.txt
STRING='$1'

grep "$(sed 's/  */\\|/g' <<<"$1")" $FILE
```

So when i run the script i do script.sh Word1 Word2 but it seems to not search word2 as well
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till what i understand your question, you mean to say matching multiple patterns?

If that's what you are asking,

```
grep 'A B\|A B C' file
```

Would print all lines with either `A B` or `A B C`.
`|` is for `this pattern | or this pattern`. It needs to be backslashed though.
For using without backslash you can supply `-E` flag.

Update:

Let's say you have all the words stored in `words`,

```
grep "$(sed 's/  */\\|/g' <<<"$words")" file
```

Comment: Dont think this is what i want, i tried this before but didnt give me the output i needed. Say i have a line such as "Word1 Word2 - Word3 Word4 Word5"
"Word1 Word6 Word3 Word7 Word8"
And in the search i search for "Word1 Word3" I want it to still output these lines as the search case matches this line.

Comment: Thanks a lot but the search_str"A C" wont necessarily be these values it could be anything up to 10 values....i feel that a for loop would be needed for this but not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user3411002, all you need to do is put those values in `search_str="word1 word2 word3 ..."`

Comment: Can i do this as variables in the script as these words could be anything, like a normal search and not specific words

Comment: @user3411002, let's say you have all those words stored in a variable `words`. So you can simply do like `grep "$(sed 's/   */\\|/g' <<<"$words")" file`

Comment: @user3411002, I have updated answer accordingly, comments  seem to remove the necessary whitespace.

Comment: I think we are getting close but its still not checking all the words, check my update to see what i have done using your valuable help

Comment: @user3411002, all you need to do it change that `$1` to `"$@"` like `grep "$(sed 's/  */\\|/g' <<<"$@")" $FILE`. Shell accepts arguments in a space delimeted manner which means `$1` only contains `Word1`. `"$@"` contains all the arguments passed to shell in a single string.

Comment: Ah great i did not know that i think we are even closer now to what i actually want. How do we combine the inputs so it checks Word1 Word2 to be on one line only instead of throughout the text file and displaying outputs where Word1 and Word2 are in seperate lines? Just want it to check for it on single lines and display the output if the search case matches. Thanks for your help appreciate it am learning too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197665/discussion-between-mihir-and-user3411002).

Answer (score 0):

grep -f reads several patterns from file